# Monitor log file size with hyperic

Tags: monitoring, log-files, hyperic

I am monitoring a number of enterprise resources with [Hyperic](http://www.hyperic.com/) and have a hard requirement to monitor their log files both for content and for size, as they have a habit of growing out of control.

Monitoring the content is easy, but I'm not sure how to monitor the file size. Is this something that can be done out of the box or would it need some groovy scripting to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done out of the box with "New Platform Service"->"FileServer File".

Note that the "File Size" metric is not enabled by default so you need to enable it by editing the metric template in Administration->Monitoring Defaults

Answer (score 1):

I had to monitor a file on a Linux server for out-of-control growth, and wanted to use Hyperic for this job.

My short, non-detailed answer:

1) Wrote a quick script to calculate the growth since the last time the script was run (using a file under /var/cache to store the file size value from the last time it was run).  The script took the file name as a parameter.

2) Using the Hyperic agent on that box, tie a "Script" Service in.  The Config added the specific filename being watched.  (There was also a "sudo" needed for me, but that's another story.)